# Javascript printed <IFRAME> not displaying content

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I've been working on a multi-slided page where javascript triggered  tags are used to change slides.

So, I have several links:

```
<html><head>
<link rel="javascript" href="script.js">
</head><body>
<a href="javascript:display1()">Slide 1</a> | <a href="javascript:display2()">Slide 2</a>
<br><span id="display"></span>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

The two links trigger the following Javascript code:
(Assuming the script is called "script.js")

```
function display1() {document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = '<iframe href="slide1.html"></iframe>';};
function display2() {document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = '<iframe href="slide2.html"></iframe>';};
```

Except, the only problem is (assuming both pages have content on them), is that it is not displaying anything at all after clicking the links. As in this is the code for the  tag:

```
<span id="display">
<iframe href="slide1.html></iframe>
</span>
```

with the document within it displaying as:

```
<span id="display">
<iframe href="slide1.html>
#document
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
</iframe>
</span>
```

Instead of:

```
<span id="display">
<iframe href="slide1.html>
#document
<html>
<head></head>
<body><b>Slide 1</b></body>
</html>
</iframe>
</span>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An iframe has no `href`, it has a `src` attribute ?

```
.innerHTML = '<iframe src="slide1.html"></iframe>';};
```